# TimeoutException using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I'm getting TimeoutException when using this code to get the fill in the CardNum textbox with a number

```
CardNUM = WebDriverWait(browser,   10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="number"]'))) 
CardNUM.send_keys(cardNum)
```

Xpath is taken directly from right clicking and inspecting the textbox and copying the XPATH for the block

```
<input autocomplete="cc-number" id="number" name="number" type="tel" aria-describedby="error-for-number" data-current-field="number" class="input-placeholder-color--lvl-30" placeholder="Card number" style="color: rgb(151, 151, 151); font-family: &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;; padding: 0.94em 0.8em; transition: padding 0.2s ease-out;">
```

Is there something else I need to do to be able to fill in the box, for example is the text box hidden and is there some manipulation that I would need to do beforehand to be able to find the text box?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the element is inside an IFRAME, especially since it seems to be a credit card number. The payment portion of payment pages are typically in an IFRAME for security. Try switching to the IFRAME first then your code should work.